# How can I deploy an iOS app to amazon EC2?

Tags: objective-c, database, database-design, amazon-ec2, backend

I am currently using Parse.com for my iOS app backend. However, I find it frustrating and limiting in many ways and I would like to switch to amazon EC2.

I have been looking for a good tutorial on how to deploy an iOS app to amazon EC2 from scratch but I could not find anything good.

Does anyone know a good tutorial that explains step by step how to setup EC2 for an iOS app?

My knowledge in backend stuff is close to zero but I am eager to learn.

Thanks!

Comment: are u saying you want to deploy your backend services on EC2?

Comment: This is difficult to answer as is - EC2 is just a fleet of servers you can create and manage via an api. Your question isn't much more specific than "how can I use a server for my iOS app backend"

Comment: @Jun1st Yes, exactly. But I don't really know where to begin. Should I use MongoDB or is there a specific software that runs on EC2 for iOS?

Comment: @FrederickCheung Good point. How can I make my question more specific? Can you put me on the right track? Thx